# Are gitignore files being automatically created in my project?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have been trying to manage the local copy of the project I am working on using EGit.

I make a pull once there is a push from the other guys. However, there are files that show that I have uncommitted changes in my local repository, but I haven't made any change. I try to resolve these by manually identifying these changes and discover that they are from gitignore files, which I didn't create myself (the files also show errors occasionally).

Is it possible that the gitignore files are being auto-created? How can I maintain a synced local repo state? I am using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: Closed as unclear? For what its worth... I had no problem understanding the question... or the answer (which was exactly what I was looking for)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is possible that the settings "Automatically ignore derived resources" triggers the generation/modification of `.gitignore`.
This is a consequence of [bug 297674](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=297674), adding that feature in EGit 2.3 (Q2 2013).

See the [EGit tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#firstegit_gitignore):

> You can also configure Eclipse to automatically ignore derived resources, e.g. class files via the **`Window → Preferences → Team → Git → Projects → Automatically ignore derived resources`** .. setting.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I will check if that is the reason.

Comment: @SyCode ok, but if did accept the answer, that should mean it was the reason, no?

Comment: i strongly suspect it, but since I haven't pulled from the project, I cannot really confirm. I will update this comment if there is a different result afterwards.

Comment: @SyCode ok, I'll integrate your comment in this answer.