# How can I prevent eclipse from randomly adding .gitignore files everywhere?

Tags: eclipse, gitignore, egit

eclipse keeps adding .gitignore files to my project that contain the following random list of files:

```
Thumbs.db
.DS_Store
.gradle
build/
out/
.idea
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.project
.settings
.classpath
/bin/
```

I know which files I want to keep out of source control. I don't need my IDE to try to second guess me.

Where is the configuration option in eclipse that prevents it from creating .gitignore files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mentioned before (2014) the setting "[`Window → Preferences → Team → Git → Projects → Automatically ignore derived resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360124/6309)"

See if that would still have an incidence in your case (with, I presume, a much more recent Eclipse version)

This was also described (more recently, in 2020) in "[Eclipse: Prevent creation of `.gitignore` for generated code](https://thomas.trocha.com/blog/eclipse-prevent-creation-of-gitigonre-for-generated-code/)" from [Thomas Trocha](https://twitter.com/dertom95)

[image: https://thomas.trocha.com/blog/content/images/2020/09/grafik.png]